# Color chart lines based on cell value not associated with chart

Tags: excel, charts

I am looking to find an automated way to color lines on a chart in excel based on a value and/or a color from a cell not associated with the chart itself.  Color based on value being the ideal solution.

The data for the chart at the link below is in cells B2:F9 and the colors I want represented are on lines C1:F1.  Based on this image, I want the chart line representing rows C and E to be green and the chart line representing D and F to be red.

[image]

In order to color the pass/fail section I currently have conditional formatting setup but am able to change this for a more effective solution.  This needs to be scaled across a large number of reports so manual color changing is not a viable option.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Share one of your conditional formulas so we can get a better idea of what you are striving for. It is not clear what criteria determines the color.

Comment: First, thank you for your willingness to assist.  The conditional formatting I have is very basic.  Sadly I can't get the image to load here but the link is: (http://postimg.org/image/5rqrhee1z/).  The goal would be to setup the data to chart based on the color I have in column 1.

Comment: The conditional formatting code is:  Cell Value contains 'fail' [format red] applies to =$C$1:$I$1 AND Cell Value contains 'pass' [format green] applies to =$C$1:$I$1.

Comment: What is the formula in cell D1? Isn't it the one that has to change to evaluate the entire column?

Comment: This excel sheet is produced from an Access Database we have and is one of hundreds of tests we want to chart in excel.  The cell D1, which says fail, is automatically generated by the database so there is no formula for it from excel.  I have been able to identify and implement a macro (http://postimg.org/image/7pidbeqdj/) which changes the lines in my chart based on the C2:I2 color because that line is integrated into my chart.  However line 2 is not the one which is affected by my conditional formatting.

Comment: Let me try to explain it in a different manner.  In my mind, the formula would be read like this: If Cell C1 is green the graph line for C column should be green OR If cell C1 says Pass the graph line for C column should be green HOWEVER if cell C1 is red the graph line for C column should be red OR If cell C1 says Fail the graph line for C column should be red.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little bit of sample code that should point you in the right direction.  It changes the color of series based on values elsewhere in the spreadsheet.  Ideally, you can modify this to suit your needs.  I am trying to highlight the key step of iterating through the series and coloring them based on an external range.  There are other questions about selecting a chart and ranges.

I am using the values of the "header" cells (pass/fail) to choose the colors.  I think it can be difficult to get the `Interior` color of a cell formatted by conditional formatting (IIRC?).

```
Sub ColorChartBasedOnOtherCells()

    'set up a range of colors that "matches" the series
    Dim rng_colors As Range
    Set rng_colors = Range("C1:F1")

    'get a reference to the chart... assume it is selected for now
    Dim cht As Chart
    Set cht = ActiveChart

    Dim ser As Series
    Dim int_index As Integer

    'iterate through series in order... assume this matches the column order
    int_index = 1
    For Each ser In cht.SeriesCollection

        'check the value of the "reference-color" cell and set series color
        If rng_colors(int_index) = "pass" Then
            ser.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Else
            ser.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        End If

        int_index = int_index + 1
    Next ser
End Sub
```

## Before

[image: before chart]

## After

[image: after with colors]